# I can't get the results of my quiz to be stored in a database

Tags: php, mysql

The results from my quiz are not storing to my database 'results'

I've tried storing my

$_session['score']

in a variable

```
 $score = $_session['score']
```

but nothing happens
Below are all my files for the quiz

**index.php** (this is the first page users see when they select quiz. This page works fine)

```
<?php include "database.php"; ?>

<?php
    //Get the total questions
    $query="select * from questions";
    //Get Results
    $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    $total = $results->num_rows;

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <?php include "nav-bar.php" ?>
    <title>Quizzer!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1>LaBoa weekly quiz</h1>
    </div>
      </header>


      <main>
      <div class="container">
        <br>
        <h2>Test your knowlege</h2>
        <br>
    <p>This is a multiple choice quize to test your knowledge about something</p>
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Number of Questions: </strong><?php echo $total; ?></ul>
        <li><strong>Type: </strong>Multiple Choice</ul>
        <li><strong>Estimated Time: </strong><?php echo $total*0.5; ?> minutes</ul>
    </ul>
    <a href="question.php?n=1" class="start">Start Quiz</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </main>


    <footer>
      <div class="container">
           Copyright &copy; 2019, LaBoa
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**process.php** (this file is where I create the $_SESSION['score']. It adds up all the answers the user get's correct.

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php

      //Check to see if score is set_error_handler
    if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
       $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    }

//Check if form was submitted
if($_POST){
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $next=$number+1;
    $total=4;

    //Get total number of questions
    $query="SELECT * FROM `questions`";
    $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    $total=$results->num_rows;

    //Get correct choice
    $q = "select * from `choices` where question_number = $number and is_correct=1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($q) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $correct_choice=$row['id'];



    //compare answer with result
    if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }

    if($number == $total){
           $score = $_POST['score'];
        header("Location: final.php");
        exit();
    } else {
            header("Location: question.php?n=".$next."&score=".$_SESSION['score']);
    }
}
?>
```

final.php (This is where the result of thr quiz is dispayed. Although the results are displayed it doesn't save to thr database)

```
 <?php include "database.php"; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
    //Create Select Query
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <?php include "nav-bar.php" ?>
    <title>
      Quizzer!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1>LaBoa Weekly Quiz</h1>
    </div>

      </header>


      <main>
    <div class="container">
         <h2>You are Done!</h2>
         <p>Congrats! You have completed the test</p>
         <p>Final socre: <?php echo $_SESSION['score']; ?></p>
         <a href="question.php?n=1" class="start">Take Test Again</a>
       <?php
       $query="INSERT into results (account_id, score, score_date)
       values('name', 'score', date)";
       ?>
         <?php session_destroy(); ?>
    </div>
      </main>


    <footer>
      <div class="container">
           Copyright &copy; 2019, LaBoa
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is the sql for my quiz**

```
-- Table structure for table `questions`
--

CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `question_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin;

--

-- Table structure for table `results`
--

CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `result_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The quiz is suppose to be part of a larger app for a school project. I'll also link files regarding th user below as they may be of help.

**register.php**

```
<?php
// Change this to your connection info.
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
if  (!isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Please complete the registration form!<br><a href="register.html">Back</a>');
}
// Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
if (empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) || empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // One or more values are empty...
    die ('Please complete the registration form!<br><a href="register.html">Back</a>');
}
// We need to check if the st_account with that username exists
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die ('Email is not valid!<br><a href="register.html">Back</a>');
  if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST['username']) == 0) {
    die ('Username is not valid!<br><a href="register.html">Back</a>');
}
if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
    die ('Password must be between 5 and 20 characters long.<br><a href="register.html">Back</a>');
}
}
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the st_account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // Username already exists
        echo 'Username exists, please choose another!<br><a href="register.html">Back</a>';
    } else {
        // Username doesnt exists, insert new st_account
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
            // We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
            $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo 'You have successfully registered, you can now login!<br><a href="index.html">Login</a>';
        } else {
            echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**authenticate.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
}
// Prepare our SQL
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the st_account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // st_account exists, now we verify the password.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            include_once 'homepage.php';
            // echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
// check to see if the user is logged in
if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    // user is logged in
    include_once 'homepage.php';
} else {
    // user is not logged in, send the user to the login page
    header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

Sorry if I posted too much or too little info, I'm just really desperate, I've been stuck on this problem for ages and I really don't know what to do. Please don't flame me in the comments I'm still learning.

**code for final.php**

```
 <?php include "database.php"; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
    //Create Select Query
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <?php include "nav-bar.php" ?>
    <title>
      Quizzer!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1>LaBoa Weekly Quiz</h1>
    </div>

      </header>


      <main>
    <div class="container">
         <h2>You are Done!</h2>
         <p>Congrats! You have completed the test</p>
         <p>Final socre: <?php echo $_SESSION['score']; ?></p>
         <a href="question.php?n=1" class="start">Take Test Again</a>
       <?php
       $con->query("INSERT into results (account_id, score, score_date)
              values($name, $score, now())");
       ?>
         <?php session_destroy(); ?>
    </div>
      </main>


    <footer>
      <div class="container">
           Copyright &copy; 2019, LaBoa
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't worry about flame. Welcome to world of PHP :)

You probably have a problem somewhere in the SQL queries. I suggest you test for some Exceptions when executing queries... And make sure to run `session_start` on every php script

Comment: fyi .. it should be $_SESSION

Comment: I don't see the query actually being executed... Also, you insert plain text, not variables of some sort.

Comment: why session_destroy in the middle of the code ? you dont have to post the entire application here . post the only insert which is not working

Answer (score 1):

I am sure if this helps, in final.php you have a query but I don't see where the query is executed and should the values be hardcoded?

```
 $query="INSERT into results (account_id, score, score_date)
       values('name', 'score', date)";
```

It should be something like so:

Looking at your result table, you need to provide the following values in your query `result_id`, `account_id`, `score` and score_date

update the results table make result_id auto increment

```
$accountId = $_SESSION['id'];
$score = $_SESSION['score'];
$scoreDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$con->query("INSERT into results (account_id, score, score_date)
       values($accountId , $score, $scoreDate )");
```

Comment: I just tried doing what you said but i got several errors. Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpstaff\quiz\final.php on line 35

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpstaff\quiz\final.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpstaff\quiz\final.php on line 35

Comment: That's because you don't have a $db variable, change $db to $con

Comment: Consider editing your question to use `PDO`'s bind param, since the OP is using bind param at other places in his code

Comment: First, this was a sample code that should be modified to fit your use case, where are you getting the values that you want to insert? i.e. name, score,

where is database.php file, how did you name the connection variable?

Comment: I'm trying to get the score from the  $_session['score'] in the final.php but I don't know if that's possible. For the name, I'm trying to get it from the authenticate.php page. $_POST['username'].  Sorry if i'm asking for too much help. I don't really understand what to do,

Comment: see my updated answer this doesn't match the result table and if you saved these values in session then you should be able to get them but I can't find where you saved these values

Comment: Yeah that should fix it

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think I'll just write in my evaluation it doesn't work and the different methods I used to try and fix it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I think the problem probably has to do with how I'm defining the variables. since they're all on different pages

Comment: Too much is wrong with the code but it should still be okay if everything is done right, you can send me a zip file with the code and DB files I can help you fix it

Comment: did you try with the new variables I added?

Comment: Send it through GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've just assigned a variable `$query` without ever executing it. Take a look at this line in your *final.php* file.

```php
<?php
       $query="INSERT into results (account_id, score, score_date)
       values('name', 'score', date)";
       ?>
         <?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

That's your last line of PHP, so you never did anything with the `$query` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I execute it?

Comment: You can do something like: $stmt = $con->prepare('insert into results (account_id, score, score_date) values (:name, :score, :date)'; $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name); ...etc and then $stmt->execute()

Comment: I just tried it but I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpstaff\quiz\final.php on line 35. I'm trying to see if I can fix it.